# Hewei Data Card Installation in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, permissions

**I bought a new data card From Amazon. Hewei-support 21mbps. 
It works great in windows 7 with the driver given.
But when i try installing it in Ubuntu, i get the following error..
Kindly Help**

```
*rakhu@rakhu-Inspiron-N5010:~/Desktop/driver$ ./install 
old path =/home/Hewei/driver
./install: line 26: kill: (3827) - Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/lib/udev/rules.d/50-Huawei-Datacard.rules’: Permission denied
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'option': Operation not permitted
/home/Hewei/driver/Uninstall: line 200: kill: (3827) - Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sbin/usbmod’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/sbin/startMobilePartner’: Permission denied
DRIVER COPY START
STA_PATH_FLAG=.
STA_PATH_FULL=/home/rakhu/Desktop/driver/install
START_PATH_DRIVER=/home/rakhu/Desktop/driver
CURRENT install from ./install
INSTALL_PATH is not set ,auto install
INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner
INSTALL_PATH is another path
rm /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver’: Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver’: Operation not permitted
DRIVER COPY END
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/sbin/usbmod’: Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/sbin/usbmod’: Operation not permitted
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/sbin/startMobilePartner’: Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/sbin/startMobilePartner’: Operation not permitted
have usb_modeswitch rules to HUAWEI DataCard: COUNT=0
3
ttyUSB%n COUNT=3
2-1.2:1.3 unbind and bind option
./install: line 176: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/unbind: Permission denied
./install: line 177: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/bind: Permission denied
COUNT_END=2
2-1.2:1.2 unbind and bind option
./install: line 176: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/unbind: Permission denied
./install: line 177: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/bind: Permission denied
COUNT_END=1
2-1.2:1.0 unbind and bind option
./install: line 176: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/unbind: Permission denied
./install: line 177: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/option/bind: Permission denied
COUNT_END=0
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'cdc_ether': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module cdc_ether: Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'usbnet': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module usbnet: Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'hw_cdc_driver': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module hw_cdc_driver: Operation not permitted
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "clean" "/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
rmmod -f hw_cdc_driver
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'hw_cdc_driver': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module hw_cdc_driver: Operation not permitted
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "modules" "/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
strip --strip-debug hw_cdc_driver.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#install -m 744 -c hw_cdc_driver.o /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/net
#depmod -a
#modprobe hw_cdc_driver
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "install"
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/hw_cdc_driver.ko’: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ‘/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/hw_cdc_driver.ko’: No such file or directory
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.dep.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.dep.bin.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.alias.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.alias.bin.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.softdep.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.symbols.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.symbols.bin.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.builtin.bin.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
depmod: ERROR: openat(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic, modules.devname.tmp, 1101, 644): Permission denied
modprobe hw_cdc_driver
modprobe: FATAL: Module hw_cdc_driver not found.
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [install] Error 2
Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build) to be all installed?
Now please enter any key to finish other installations.
NDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used.
USBSERIAL_TARGET_PATH = 
ACM_TARGET_PATH = 
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/xdg/autostart/HuaweiAutoStart.desktop’: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/xdg/autostart/HuaweiAutoStart.desktop’: No such file or directory
find: `/home/rakhu/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
find: `/home/rakhu/.gvfs': Permission denied
AUTORUNPATH=/home/rakhu/.config/autostart
find: `/root/': Permission denied
find: `/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
find: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority': Permission denied
find: `/etc/dhcp/ddns-keys': Permission denied
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d
‘/etc/rc2.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc2.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d
‘/etc/rc4.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc4.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d
‘/etc/rc3.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc3.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d
‘/etc/rc5.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc5.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
qmi_wwan interface not exist,ok
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49huawei’: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49huawei’: No such file or directory*
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it as sudo user.

```
chmod +x install

sudo ./install
```